# XML Deserialize and return part of the object as XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Dont know even how to search for this, but when I deserialize an xml string, I want it to return the first level of the XML:

String:
    `<pkt><cmd>logreq</cmd><data><name>scott</name><password>abc123</password><designator>R233</designator><token>123456</token></data></pkt>`

When I use this code:

```
    class xmlFunctions
{
    public Cmd GetCmd(string sXML)
    {
        Cmd cmd = new Cmd();
        try
        {
            var sr = new StringReader(sXML);
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cmd));
            cmd = (Cmd)xs.Deserialize(sr);
            return cmd;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
           Console.WriteLine("Cannot Parse Input.");
        }
        return cmd;
    }
}
```

and this is my Cmd object:

```
[XmlRoot("pkt")]
public class Cmd
{
    public string cmd { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }

}
```

I would expect that Cmd.cmd = logreq
and                 Cmd.data = `<name>scott</name><password>abc123</password><designator>R233</designator><token>123456</token>`

but the data = scott.

How do I get it to return the XML part above?  it seems that it wants to deserialize all the xml and not just the first level?

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 c#

Answer (score 0):

I think you really mean **Parse a XML string and return the `root` node.** In that case this is what you're looking for [How to Parse XML with XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: What I am planning on doing is based on the cmd (in this case login request) I would then like to pass the data xml on to another reader that expects the different tags.   So if the cmd is searchFi, it might have different types of tags in the data node.  I would then use a switch statement to pass just the data on to another xmlreader function.